# Black Patent and stout

Tags: stout, recipe

The debate rages on so I thought I'd ask.

Do you think black patent (black barley) belongs in Stout?  Or is stout better made with just roasted barely and chocolate malts, while BP is best reserved for Porter?

I am of the camp that if it tastes good do what you like.
I make a really nice Oatmeal Stout, that uses primarily roasted barley.  But I find that I like just about 2oz of BP in there for and added level of roasted depth.

Comment: Yeahm I don't know where some opinions of what goes into beer or not comes from.  In the end its about taste and satisfaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure about "official style guidelines", but I made a double chocolate stout with an exorbitant amount of black patent.

It's awesome.

Surprisingly the roasted flavor meets the chocolate very well, making it an unconventionally unsweet chocolate stout.

+1 for going with what you like.

Comment: Always +1 for going with what you like.